# Where is this json member defined

Tags: angularjs

In this code taken from angular.org:

[angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br />
E-mail: <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br />
Gender: <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male" />male
<input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="female" />female<br />
<button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
<button ng-click="update(user)">SAVE</button>
</form>
<pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
<pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
function Controller($scope) {
   $scope.master= {};

   $scope.update = function(user) {
     // Example with 1 argument
     $scope.master= angular.copy(user);
   };

   $scope.reset = function() {
     // Example with 2 arguments
     angular.copy($scope.master, $scope.user);
   };

   $scope.reset();
 }
</script>
```

I can't determine where the json member is being defined. I've seen this in many of the examples on the site. What does it evaluate to?

Comment: It's not a member, it's a filter, and it's probably a standard filter defined in the angular library itself.

Comment: Indeed, it's a filter to display variable as a JSON, build in angular

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a filter and it is part of angular's code  - [github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L491)

```
function jsonFilter() {
  return function(object) {
    return toJson(object, true);
  };
}
```